# Soma de valores em Array retorna NaN

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Eu tenho um array de pedidos, mais um deles contem um valor adicional. Fiz a soma com $watchCollection, mais ele está retornando resultado NaN. Como faz pra somar esses valores, quando o objeto não tem o valor adicional.

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.seuPedido = [
{nome: 'produto 1', valor: 10.00, quantidade: 3},
{nome: 'produto 2', valor: 20.00, quantidade: 1},
{nome: 'produto 3', valor: 30.50, quantidade: 1, adicional: 10}
];

$scope.$watchCollection('seuPedido',function() {
$scope.total = 0;
angular.forEach($scope.seuPedido, function(value, key) {
  $scope.total += value.quantidade * (value.valor + value.adicional);
  console.log($scope.total)
})
});

});
```

Segue o codepen: http://codepen.io/alexandre_developer/pen/bpwzzB?editors=0011

Comment: Não teria nenhuma regra pro valor adicional? Como deve ser o calculo caso ele não exista?

Comment: Não seria legal tipo você colocar um if Ternario antes de fazer a soma, algo como `var valorAdicional =  value.adicional == undefined? 0 : value.adicional;$scope.total += value.quantidade * (value.valor + valorAdicional);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na sua função de cálculo assuma um valor *default* para os itens que não possuem a propriedade `adicional`:

```
$scope.total += value.quantidade * (value.valor + (value.adicional || 0));
//                 Operador 'Coalesce': Valor, ou caso nulo zero --^
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui @lbotinelly. Valeu pela dica. Resolvi não esse, mais outros problemas que eu tava tendo aqui. Valeu pela força!

Comment: @AlexandreScrideli fico feliz que tenha funcionado - e é sempre um prazer ajudar. =)

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o elemento valor adicional:0 nos produtos que não tem valor adicional.

Comment: Mais esse array que eu fiz é um exemplo. O array q eu preciso inserir o código, é de um push, e alguns objetos não retornam o valor adicional

Comment: sem problemas, assim que receber a collection itere ele colocando o valor adicional=0 em cada elemento.   for (var i=0; i<$scope.seuPedido.length;i++) {
   $scope.seuPedido[i].adicional=0;
}

Comment: Só coloque um if antes de atribuir 0 para apenas os que estiverem com o atributo como undefined: if(!$scope.seuPedido[i].adicional)